# Why does the rails scaffold use respond_to blocks in the create, update and destroy actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From what I understand, these actions are usually triggered after a form is submitted.  I can't imagine any reason why a form would generate json, in other words, (assuming a hypothetical controller is named 'UsersController') I can't imagine when or how a form would take my browser to:

```
localhost:3000/users.json
```

wouldn't post requests automatically take the user to:

```
localhost:3000/users
```

...and hence automatically to html?  And furthermore, if they arrived here, at:

```
localhost:3000/users
```

and typed in:

```
localhost:3000/users.json
```

wouldn't this just be a GET request back to index.json?  And hence back to the index action?...rendering json in that particular action via a GET request (not the create action, via POST)?

I'm confused and can't understand how anyone could ever end up at users.json from a POST request, and hence I can't imagine why a respond_to block that renders json makes sense in these actions.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails assumes that the controller actions might also be accessed as an API and not just via the browser. In such cases it makes sense to respond to those requests differently instead of redirecting the client (browser) to the index or show action.

When you create a resource from an API client, it might not make sense to redirect the user to the index or show action instead of just responding to the client that the resource was created (or not). Same applies for the update and destroy actions.